# Is the count operation still a serious limit in Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I am seeing this limit for count queries:

"We currently limit count operations to 160 api requests within a one minute period for each application. We may have to adjust this in the future depending on database performance.
The limit applies to all requests made by all clients of the application. If you need to query counts more frequently, you may want to design your system so the results can be cached in your client application."

Has anyone found a workaround or do I need to stop using count queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can either cache the count result using SharedPreferences, or use cloud code and store the counts in a separate ParseObject.

Client side using Android: 
modify the TTL according to your needs.

```
private static final long COUNT_RESULT_TTL = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1);
...
public long getGamesCount() {
    long lastUpdateTimestamp = getSharedPreferences().getLong(PREF_LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP, 0);
    if (lastUpdateTimestamp < (new Date().getTime() - COUNT_RESULT_TTL) {
        return getSharedPreferences().getLong(PREF_GAMES_RESULT_COUNT, 0);
    } else {
        return getGamesCountFromParse();
    }
}
```